# How do I test a public function that has private method dependency?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, httpclientfactory

I'm trying to test a public method (Method A) that consumes an HttpClient to access an external API. This public method calls a private method (Method B) of the same class to get an Access Token that is required by the HttpClient of Method A to send the request. The problem I am having is that I am creating a mock of the HttpClientFactory interface in order to test the response of the Method A, but in order for Method B get the token it needs its own instance of HttpClient. Therefore, the mock instance created in the Test method will be used by the Method B as well, and it will fail trying to get the Access Token. The following code makes the scenario more clear.

Method to be tested (Method A):

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(string requestUri, string siteName, int accountId)
{
  try
  {
    var accessToken = await GetTokenAsync(siteName, accountId);
    if (accessToken == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Error Sending request - Could not find an access token");

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{accessToken.Api}{requestUri}");

    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.Accesstoken);

    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    return await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception("Error Sending request.", e);
  }
}
```

Test Method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ShouldReturnHttpResponseMessage_OnSendAsync()
{

  //_jaClientMock.Setup(x => x.GetTokenAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Verifiable();

  _appSettingsMock.Setup(x => x.Value)
    .Returns(GetValidFakeAppSettings());

  HttpResponseMessage expectedResponse = GetListOfContacts(HttpStatusCode.OK, false);
  _httpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateClient())
    .Returns(GetMockedHttpClient(expectedResponse));

  var response = await _jaClient.SendAsync("someurl", "siteName", 1000);

  response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

The private Method (Method B):

```
 private async Task<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(string siteName, int accountId)
{
  try
  {
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(GetCacheKeyForToken(siteName, accountId), out AccessToken value))
      return value;
    ....

    var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      accessToken = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccessToken>();
    }

    .....  
    return accessToken;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new Exception("Error Getting an Access Token.", e);
  }
}
```

Any idea How I can test Method A?

Comment: This looks like a case of tight coupling to implementation concerns which make testing in isolation difficult. The trouble you are experiencing should be seen as a sign that the code needs to be refactored. review your current design.

Comment: @Nkosi , I Understand. I am trying to avoid to refactor code to unit test it. So from your perspective there is no way to test method A?

Comment: No that is not what I meant. You can test it, just not easily. Note I said difficult, not impossible. Your issue is most likely how you setup the use of HttpClient. But since that code is not shown, it cannot be assessed.

Comment: Right. Yeah i decided to refactor, extract the private method and test it by its public interface.

Comment: Well done. Glad you found a solution. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There ain't no such thing as a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) - if one wants to unit-test some code with external dependencies, then **each and every of those external dependencies has to be mocked**.

Or one can go one step up the [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html) to integration tests (though it is not our case, probably).

So, you could:

1. Either mock the Token response in the `_httpClientFactory` the same way you mock it for the `SendAsync` ( `..._httpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.CreateClient()).Returns(GetMockedHttpClient(expectedResponse));...`)
2. Or reorganize code in such a manner that tokens are not retrieved directly from API - create some single-method `ITokenProvider` interface that will be a bit easier to mock.

   ```
   public interface ITokenProvider
   {
       public async Task<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(string siteName, int accountId);
   }
   ...
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(string requestUri, string siteName, int accountId)
   {
     try
     {
       var accessToken = await _tokenProvider.GetTokenAsync(siteName, accountId);
   ...
   [Fact]
   public async Task ShouldReturnHttpResponseMessage_OnSendAsync()
   {
       var tokenProviderMock = new Mock<ITokenProvider>()
           .Setup(o => o.GetTokenAsync("siteName", 1000))
           .Returns(Constants.AllowedToken);
       _jaClient = new JaClient(tokenProviderMock.Object);...
   ```

Comment: Sorry. For Option 2:  I do not what u mean with "The same way you mock the SendAsync" . I am not mocking SendAsync, that is actually the method i want to test. I am mocking the response of _httpClientFactory for the SendAsync Method I am testing, but how i can have 2 mocks of the _httpClientFactory one for the SendAsync and one for the GetTokenAsync.

Comment: @D.B Typo - meant " for the `SendAsync` "

Comment: Could you please be a bit more explicit with an example. Thanks.